# Triangle with a circle having an altitude as its diameter: proof of a property without using crossratios

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, metric-spaces, projective-geometry

I´ve been thinking about this problem for 3 days:

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle, $D, E,$ and $F$ the feet of the altitudes of $A, B$ and $C$, respectively. Let;
>
> 1. $O$ be the midpoint of segment $AD$
> 2. $c$ be the circle with center $O$ passing through $A$ and $D$
> 3. $X$ and $Y$ the intersections of $c$ with $AB$ and $AC$, respectively
> 4. $P$ the intersection of $XY$ with $AD$, and $Q$ the intersection of $AD$ and $EF$.
>
> Prove that $P$ is the midpoint of the segment $QD$.

I have proved that $XY$ and $EF$ are parallel lines by using inscribed angles. Someone helped me solve this problem via cross ratios. The following is his solution;

> It's easy to show that $BCXY$ is cyclic, then $EF\parallel XY$ so if
> $XY,EF$ intersect $BC$ at $G$ and $S$ respectively and if $T$ is the reflection of $D$ in $G$ then;
> $$GX\cdot GY=GB\cdot GC=GD^2$$
> $$\implies (B,C;D,T)=-1.$$
> Thus $S$ and $T$ coincide. Since $G$ is midpoint of $DS,$ we know that $P$ is the midpoint of $QD.$

I don´t understand how he applies cross ratio, and I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how he solves the problem or if someone could solve the problem without using projective geometry.

This is my visual proof that EF and XY are parallels
[image: This is my visual proof that EF and XY are parallels.]

Comment: Have you thought to use properties of the so-called orthic triangle DEF ?

Comment: Yes, but im not sure if I can get something useful

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your non-informative title "Can someone help me in the solution to a math olympiad problem (projective geometry)?" into something more meaningful "Triangle with a circle having an altitude as its diameter: proof of a property without using crossratios " that could attract people now and in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

See this link from AoPS blog (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1016535_harmonic_divisions__a_powerful_amp_rarely_used_tool). Proof of Theorem $4$ uses a construction that can be used to prove that $P$ is the midpoint of $QD$. But instead of repeating that work, I will use theorem $4$ to show that points $T,C, D$ and $B$ are in harmonic range i.e. $~\displaystyle \frac{CT}{CD} = \frac{BT}{BD}$. Then use theorem $1$ to conclude that $S$ is the midpoint of $TD$.

As $CDHE$ is cyclic, $\angle HED = \angle HCD = 90^\circ - \angle B$ and hence $\angle CED = \angle B$. Also as $BCEF$ is cyclic, $\angle BEF = \angle BCF = 90^\circ - \angle B$ and $\angle CET = \angle B$

So $(i) ~EC$ bisects $ \angle DET $ and $(ii) ~\angle BEC = 90^\circ$. Those two statements mean that pencil $~E~ (TD; CB)$ forms a harmonic range as shown in Theorem $4$.

Now using $BCEF$ as cyclic, note that $\angle CFE = \angle CBE = 90^\circ - \angle C$.
So, $\angle AYX = \angle AFE = \angle C ~~(\text {given } EF \parallel XY$, which you have already shown).

That leads to $BCXY$ being cyclic. Hence,
$SC \cdot SB = SX \cdot SY = SD^2$

Using converse of theorem $1$, $S$ must be the midpoint of $TD$ and using $EF \parallel XY$, that proves $P$ is the midpoint of $QD$.

Comment: When I apply the Theorem 4,  I get that E (TD;CB) is a harmonic range. How I can make to get your result?

Comment: If $E (TD; CB)$ is a harmonic range and there is a point $S$ on segment $TD$ such that $SD^2 = SC \cdot SB$, then $S$ must be midpoint of $TD$. Please see theorem $1$ in the same link, that is derived from these points being in harmonic range. The converse is also true.

Comment: Sure, what  I mean is that in that page the theorem 4 says that O(A,B;C,D) is a harmonic range if  $OB$ bisects $\angle AOC$ internally.
and $OB$ and $OD$ are perpendicular to each other. But I think that instead of OB we need to put OC. In addition in the proof of that theorem uses a picture when as I say the bisector is OC instead of OB. In that case, how would Theorem 4 be proved?

Comment: The proof in the link has a few typos. Let's go by the diagram then we have points $A, C, B$ and $D$ in that order and we will show that $AC/CB = AD/BD$.  We draw $FE$ through $B$ parallel to $OA$. $\angle AOC = \angle COB = \theta~$ (say). We see $\angle OEF = \angle AOE = \theta$ so $OB = BE$. $\angle OBF = 2 \theta$ and as $\angle BOF = 90^\circ - \theta$, $OB = BF$ or we could have simply figured that $B$ is the circumcenter of right triangle $EOF$. By angle bisector, $AC/CB = AO/OB = AO/BF = AD/BD$, given $AO \parallel BF$.

Comment: From here, adding and subtracting $1$ on both sides and dividing is what is used in theorem $1$.